# Web Service in Spring and Portlet environment

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I am beginner in Web Service and using

1. Spring 3.0 and spring-webmvc-portlet 3.0
2. javax.portlet 2.0

I have controller as follows

```
@Controller(value = "myController")

@RequestMapping(value = "**VIEW**")

public class MyController {

 // Controller logic

}
```

Now, I want to create Web Service using RESTful API in portlet environment.
Please guide me How can i write the Web Service which will return JSON or XML data.

---

I am still struggling with Web Service not getting WS called.

I am pasting my conf files

1. web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/itemCatalog-portlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webServiceTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webServiceTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myWebService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

1. item-portlet.xml

   ```
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.main.mypackage" />


   <bean
       class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
       <property name="webBindingInitializer">
           <bean
               class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
               <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
                   <list>
                       <ref bean="myPropertyEditorRegistrar" />
                   </list>
               </property>

           </bean>
       </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="messageSource"
       class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basenames">
           <list>
               <value>content.Language-ext</value>
           </list>
       </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass"
           value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

   <bean name="jsonView"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
       <property name="prefixJson" value="false" />
   </bean>


   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
   ```
2. webServiceTest-servlet.xml

   ```
   <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
       p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
   ```

   1. portlet.xml

   itemCatalog
           org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet
           
               text/html
               view
           
           content.Language-ext
3. Controller

   @Controller
   public class WebServiceTest {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/myWebService/testing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMethod() {
        return "HELLO WORLD ! SUCCESS";
    }

   }

I am trying to Hit with

localhost:8080:/myappname/myWebService/testing

Getting no result.

Comment: Can I use DispatcherServlet configuration ? To configure Web Service

Answer (score 0):

To create Web Service in portlet environment. 
1. We need to use org. springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet which is front controller for all the controllers available. All the HTTP request will be dispatched using Dispatcher servlet.

Add an entry in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>springwebservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springwebservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please refer below link for dispatcher servlet read carefully

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

1. Now importantly each DispatcherServlet must have own WebApplicationContext. WebApplicationContext is nothing but an xml file comprises of controllers,view resolver,beans,etc .

Create file named springwebservice-servlet.xml in WEB-INF. springwebservice-servlet.xml is a WebApplicationContext.

Note

Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global scope.

Make sure new WebAppicationContext is created for DispatcherServlet and configure it according to need.

**Please guide me if mistaken somewhere.**